# Catching Syntax Errors from iPython Kernel

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

The way to connect, run, display, show errors over inprocess ipython kernel is

```
import re, sys, time, os
from StringIO import StringIO
from IPython.kernel.inprocess.blocking import BlockingInProcessKernelClient
from IPython.kernel.inprocess.manager import InProcessKernelManager
from IPython.kernel.inprocess.ipkernel import InProcessKernel
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
from IPython.utils.io import capture_output

def decorated_run_code(fn):
    def new_run_code(*args, **kwargs):
        res = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(args[0], "last_known_outflag", res)
        return res
    return new_run_code
InteractiveShell.run_code = decorated_run_code(InteractiveShell.run_code)    

km = InProcessKernelManager()
km.start_kernel()
kc = BlockingInProcessKernelClient(kernel=km.kernel)
kc.start_channels()
kc.shell_channel.execute('%pylab inline')
kernel = InProcessKernel()    
ip = kernel.shell.get_ipython()

with capture_output() as io:
    ip.run_cell(fail)
print "res", io.stdout
etype, value, tb = kernel.shell._get_exc_info(None)
print kernel.shell.last_known_outflag
if kernel.shell.last_known_outflag: print (etype, "/", value, "/", tb)
```

I had to decorate run_code to capture its result and set it on self, because _get_exc_info returns the same error until another one occurs, so there was no other way to see if an error occured or not. If anyone has a better method I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error conditions are much easier to catch in iptyhon 3.0, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301819/executing-python-code-in-ipython-kernel/20346583#20346583).